# ggplot2: "Error: Must request at least one colour from a hue palette." for plotting spatial problem solution

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a list of spatial problems that I was able to solve using Prioritizr but I can't plot the solution.

This is the list of problems:

```
p <- readRDS("Input/Problems/01b_ProblemsIUCNLong.rds")
```

And this is the code I used to solve it:

```
s2 <- lapply(readRDS("Input/Problems/01b_ProblemsIUCNLong.rds"), function(x) {
    f <- solve(x, force= TRUE) %>% 
      st_as_sf(sf_column_name = "geometry")
    
    ff <- f %>% mutate(Selected_Area = round(nrow(f[f$solution_1 == 1,])/nrow(f), 1)*100)
  } )
```

However, I can't seem to be able to plot it and keep on getting the same error:

```
IUCNonlyTarget10_withLP_plot <- ggplot() + 
+     geom_sf(data = s2[[1]], aes(fill = as.factor(solution_1), color = NA, size = 0.02, show.legend = FALSE)) +
+     scale_fill_manual(name = "Solution",
+                       values = pal_rich,
+                       labels = solution) +
+     geom_sf(data = world_sf, size = 0.05, fill = "grey20") +
+     coord_sf(xlim = c(st_bbox(Bndry)$xmin, st_bbox(Bndry)$xmax), 
+              ylim = c(st_bbox(Bndry)$ymin, st_bbox(Bndry)$ymax),
+              expand = TRUE) +
+     ggtitle("Target 10%") +
+     theme_bw() +
+     ggsave("Output/Figs/IUCNonlyTarget10_withLP_06.pdf", width = 20, height = 10, dpi = 300) +
+     ggsave("Output/Figs/IUCNonlyTarget10_withLP_06.png", width = 20, height = 10, dpi = 300)

Error: Must request at least one colour from a hue palette.
In addition: Warning message:
Ignoring unknown aesthetics: show.legend
```

Any idea of I might fix this?

I tried removing `color = NA` and I tried putting it outside of `aes()` but I am getting an empty layer in my plot... even though I checked it is not an empty layer...

This is what I'm getting
[image]

while it should be something like that
[image]

Any advice?

Comment: Try with removing `color = NA` from aes() or move it outside of `aes()`

Comment: I tried, I don't have the error anymore but I am getting an empty plot... although I checked my layer is not empty...

Answer (score 0):

It is a misplacement in the brackets

```
IUCNonlyTarget10_withLP_plot <- ggplot() + 
+     geom_sf(data = s2[[1]], aes(fill = as.factor(solution_1)), color = NA, size = 0.02, show.legend = FALSE) +
+     scale_fill_manual(name = "Solution",
+                       values = pal_rich,
+                       labels = solution) +
+     geom_sf(data = world_sf, size = 0.05, fill = "grey20") +
+     coord_sf(xlim = c(st_bbox(Bndry)$xmin, st_bbox(Bndry)$xmax), 
+              ylim = c(st_bbox(Bndry)$ymin, st_bbox(Bndry)$ymax),
+              expand = TRUE) +
+     ggtitle("Target 10%") +
+     theme_bw() +
+     ggsave("Output/Figs/IUCNonlyTarget10_withLP_06.pdf", width = 20, height = 10, dpi = 300) +
+     ggsave("Output/Figs/IUCNonlyTarget10_withLP_06.png", width = 20, height = 10, dpi = 300)
```